# manually generated events now showing up in analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have checked out several questions on SO but the answers/tips didn't work for me. I am trying to send events manually (no Tag manager) when a specific link is clicked. I followed this [tutorial](https://searchenginewatch.com/2018/03/19/how-to-set-up-event-tracking-in-google-analytics/) but still I can't see my event. On GA dashboard real-time, I see the following:

[image]

my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Fiver</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- insert your google analytics stuff here -->

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GAID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA-ID');
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a
      href="javascript:void(0);"
      onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Logs', eventAction: 'new log', eventLabel: 'Danger', eventValue: 50});"
      >Send Data</a
    >
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in that the tutorial is wrong. They even referenced the wrong documentation. Your GA implementation is done through gtag.js, the correct documentation to follow would be here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

so you need to change your on click to be

```
  onClick="gtag('event', 'new log', {'event_category': 'Logs', 'event_label': 'Danger', 'value': 50});"
```