# Event click tracking for Google Analytics is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics, event-handling

I have three links that I want to track the clicking off on my WordPress site (http://baytrail.org/thirty/). I had to add an additional Google Analytics Tracking code, due to not having access to the second one. I can't remove either one. When I try to add code to track the links, nothing is reported back to the Google Analytics portal. Please help me resolved this issue

Notes:
There are two google analytics tracking codes

The first GA code (I purposely added the XXXs for privacy ID)

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The newly added GA code

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-1');
</script>
```

The three tracking code options I have tried, none seem to work:

1. onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'PDF Downloads', 'Click', 'Map Download Button');"
2. gtag('event', click, {
   'event_category': links,
   'event_label': Contest Rules,
   'value': 1
   });
3. ga('link', 'click', 'CTA Map Download Link');

When I look into GA real-time events, nothing is showing. Can't seem to connect/trigger the event link handlers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [manually generated events now showing up in analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146458/manually-generated-events-now-showing-up-in-analytics)

Comment: Is the 2nd `gtag('event', click)` really like this? If so change it to `gtag('event', 'click' ....)`.

Comment: If you leave the first GA code up, which uses `analytics.js`, your first onclick attempt should work (although it should be `onclick`, not `onClick`). I tested it on your site, and saw the event fire as a `/collect` GET request, as well as in the Google Tag Assistant. Are you sure you don't have any view filters set up that might be accidentally filtering out users? Other things to check is that any ad-blocking you might have installed is off when checking yourself, making sure the UA ID in the code matches the account you are looking at, and make sure you are looking at the real time report.